# The given key was not present in the dictionary while retrieving pre-image entity crm 2013

Tags: crm

i have registered pre_image with the name 'prentity' and alias 'prentity' and i am retrieving
it as follow

Entity pentity = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["prentity"];

but giving error  'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Comment: I think Renjith might be right. I would double check the spelling of the pre-image name as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have registered the plugin in create mode the preimage will not be available. May be that is the reason why that image is not available.

Please refer the link below where it explains about the pre and post images.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2010/07/26/pre-image-38-post-image-explained-33.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don`t register pre-image.

My piece of advice: It is depend on situation, but you can use Target.

Example:

```
Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
```

Target contain all fields that user has fill up.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to get preImage:

```
var currentRecord= (context.PreEntityImages != null && context.PreEntityImages.Contains("prentity")) ? context.PreEntityImages["prentity"] : null;
```

NB: you can not use preImage for an "OnCreate" Message,